# Imputation in large data

Tags: r, imputation

I need to impute missing values. My data set has about 800,000 rows and 92 variables. I tried kNNImpute in the imputation package in r but looks like the data set is too big. Any other packages/method in R? I would prefer not to use mean to replace the missing values. 
thank you

Comment: There is even a task view for imputation on CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/OfficialStatistics.html But probably you this question is better suited on stats.exchange.com? Maybe you should also explain in which way your "data set is too big".

Comment: I have a similar problem with a dataset of aprox 800000 rows and 15 variables. I want to impute missing values with `VIM::kNN` but I get the error message:`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 113.1 Gb`,  which is more then my machines RAM ofcourse. any suggestions?

Comment: Same issue here. I am trying to use VIM::kNN on a dataset with ~600k rows and 6 columns. The size of the original file in CSV is 34Mb but the function results in an error that it `cannot allocate vector of size 354.0 Gb`. I really don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

1) You might try

```
library(sos)
findFn("impute")
```

This shows 400 matches in 113 packages.  This shows 400 matches in 113 packages: you could narrow it down per your requirements of the imputation function.

2) Did you see/try [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) ?

> Description: The Hmisc library contains many functions useful for data
>           analysis, high-level graphics, utility operations, functions
>           for computing sample size and power, importing datasets,
>           imputing missing values, advanced table making, variable
>           clustering, character string manipulation, conversion of S
>           objects to LaTeX code, and recoding variables.

3) Possibly [mice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html)

> Multiple imputation using Fully Conditional Specification (FCS)
>   implemented by the MICE algorithm. Each variable has its own
>   imputation model. Built-in imputation models are provided for
>   continuous data (predictive mean matching, normal), binary data
>   (logistic regression), unordered categorical data (polytomous logistic
>   regression) and ordered categorical data (proportional odds). MICE can
>   also impute continuous two-level data (normal model, pan, second-level
>   variables). Passive imputation can be used to maintain consistency
>   between variables. Various diagnostic plots are available to inspect
>   the quality of the imputations.

Answer (score 3):

MICE is a great package, with strong diagnostic tools, and may be capable of doing the job in such a large dataset.

One thing you should be aware of: MICE is S-L-O-W. Working on such a big dataset, if you intend to use MICE, I would strongly recommend you to use a computing cloud -- otherwise, you're better planning your self in advance because, with a 800k x ~100 matrix, it may take a few days to get the job done, depending on how you specify your model.

MICE offers you a number of different imputation methods to be used according to the type of variable to be imputed. The fastest one is predictive mean matching. PMM was initially intended to be used to impute continuous data but it seems pmm is flexible enough to accomodate other types of variable. Take a look at this Paul Allison's post and Stef van Buuren's response: http://statisticalhorizons.com/predictive-mean-matching

(I see this is a three years old post but I have been using MICE and have been amazed by how powerful -- and oftentimes slow -- it can be!)